# Inserting data into a table returns with insertId 0

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I used CodeIgniter as a framework for my development.
I am trying to insert data to a table at MySQL database.
Data is inserted as follows.

```
$dataArray['categoryId'] = $categoryId['id'];
$dataArray['subCategoryId'] = $subTypeId;
$dataArray['title'] = $title;
$dataArray['regionId'] = $regionId;
$dataArray['slogan'] = $slogan;
$dataArray['lastUpdated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dataArray['createdDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dataArray['state'] = 'Unhide';
$dataArray['status'] = 'Active';
$dataArray['approval'] = 'Incompleted';
$dataArray['user_id'] = $userId;
$this->db->insert($carrentals, $dataArray);
$insertId = $this->db->insert_id();
```

My table is structured as in the attached image.
[image]

$insertId always returns 0 and no data is inserted into the table.
I can manually insert data into the table.
What could be wrong?
I have AUTO_INCREMENT column as id. But no data is inserted and always returns 0.

EDIT:
My actual code is

```
$dataArray = [
            'categoryId' => $categoryId['id'],
            'subCategoryId' => $subTypeId,
            'title' => $title,
            'regionId' => $regionId,
            'slogan' => $slogan,
            'lastUpdated' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ];
if (empty($_POST['referenceId'])) {
                $dataArray['createdDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $dataArray['state'] = 'Unhide';
                $dataArray['status'] = 'Active';
                $dataArray['approval'] = 'Incompleted';
                $dataArray['user_id'] = $userId;
                $this->db->insert($carrentals, $dataArray);
                $insertId = $this->db->insert_id();                
                $responseArray = array(
                    'result' => $insertId,
                    'success' => true);
                return $this->set_response($responseArray, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
  }
```

Comment: try rechecking table name, and columns. You can try printing `$this->db->last_query();` to see if your query is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably returning FALSE not zero. `insert()` returns TRUE or FALSE, check the results before proceeding

```
$inserted = $this->db->insert($carrentals, $dataArray);
if($inserted)
{
     $responseArray = ['result' => $insertId, 'success' => true];
}
else
{
     $responseArray = ['result' => NULL, 'success' => false];
}

return $this->set_response($responseArray, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

I don't see any problem with the way you create `$dataArray`.

Comment: Yes correct, it was FALSE not zero. The table is created, then don't know what is the reason I can't insert. The problem was solved by cloning the similar table. I tried to create to be the same as the table I cloned. But can't insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your **$dataArray** for

```
$dataArray = array( 'categoryId' => $categoryId['id'],
                    'subCategoryId' => $subTypeId,
                    'title' => $title,
                    'regionId' => $regionId,
                    'slogan' => $slogan,
                    'lastUpdated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'createdDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'state' => 'Unhide',
                    'status' => 'Active',
                    'approval' => 'Incompleted',
                    'user_id' => $userId
                 );
$this->db->insert($carrentals, $dataArray);
$insertId = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: Still the same. My actual code is as shown in the EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Try to checking how is the query with `$this->db->last_query();`, additionally check relations (if you have it), if `userId` or `categoryId` are empty.

-- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html